# Where can I report if I find a fail in the website?

Tags: support, reporting

I like the SO website and the rules are very good, but sometimes I find something not that good, and I feel like I need to report it.

So where can I report whenever I find something next time ?

Do I report here in meta? if yes, are there any special tags which should to be assigned to the post?

P.S: I don't want to get down-voted when I report an issue, just because its not a question

Comment: You are at right place..

Comment: thanks @Raynold do I have to use any special tag ?

Comment: Yes there, but dont worry if you fail to put those tags in your question. there are other experienced users who can edit your question and put proper tags.

Comment: *"I don't want to get down-voted when I report an issue, just because its not a question"*...don't worry. If it's a genuine bug, by all means report it. And if you're looking for support, do ask. Just make sure you look around first to see if it hasn't been discussed before.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that votes here are not the same as on SO http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @AshRj, yes but I don't like to be down-voted any where in the glob :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends.

1. Are you reporting a bug? Then yes, report it here on Meta Stack Overflow and use the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag
2. Are you reporting a post where someone is breaking the rules? That's what the "flag for moderator attention" feature is for
3. If it's something else, then discussing it here on Meta Stack Overflow is probably the right thing to do. Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) tags as appropriate.

Your question here is a little short on specifics and it appears that English isn't your first language. If I've misunderstood you can you clarify your question?

Comment: thanks, and yes, English is my third languages :( I'll try to edit and explain better

Comment: I've edited, but not too much, as fas as I could :s